# SQL JOIN múltiplas tabelas

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

Tenho 4 tabelas que preciso extrair os resultados, mas sempre obtenho registros duplicados, alguém pode ajudar?

```
tabclientes:
codcli nome
1       A
2       B
3       C


tabrepre:
codrepre nome
1         AA
2         AB
3         AC

tabvendedor:
codrepre  codvend  nome
1          1        BA
1          2        BB
2          1        BC
3          1        BD

tabrepcli
codcli  codrepre codvend
1        1         2
2        1         1
3        3         1
```

Meu SQL:

```
SELECT
     tabclientes.nome,
     tabvendedor.nome
FROM
     tabclientes 
     inner join tabrepcli USING (codcli)
     inner join tabrepre USING (codrepre)
     inner join tabvendedor USING (codvend)
```

O resultado duplica os registros do nome do cliente. Já tentei `distinct` mas não resolveu.

Comment: que resultado você espera?

Comment: Eu espero a lista dos nomes dos clientes com o vendedor ou primeiro vendedor.(existem outros campos e tabelas envolvidas no select, mas estas estão dando dor de cabeça). Ele está atualmente duplicando as linhas de dados dos clientes para cada representante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente eu vou criar as tabelas, da mesma forma que voce mencionou ae, populando elas:

Tabela cliente

```
postgres=# create table tabclientes (codcli int, nome varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into tabclientes (codcli, nome) values (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C');
INSERT 0 3
```

Tabela repre

```
postgres=# create table tabrepre (codrepre int, nome varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into tabrepre (codrepre, nome) values (1, 'AA'), (2, 'AB'), (3, 'AC');
INSERT 0 3
```

Tabela Vendedor

```
postgres=# create table tabvendedor (codrepre int, codvend int, nome varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into tabvendedor (codrepre, codvend, nome) values (1, 1, 'BA'), (1, 2, 'BB'), (2, 1, 'BC'), (3, 1, 'BD');
INSERT 0 4
```

Tabela unindo todo mundo

```
postgres=# create table tabrepcli (codcli int, codrepre int, codvend int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into tabrepcli (codcli, codrepre, codvend) values (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1), (3, 3, 1);
INSERT 0 3
```

Feito isso, vamos analisar sua tabela. A tabela `tabreprcli` junta o cliente, o vendedor e o representante (acho que eh esse o significado). Quando juntamos o representante e o cliente atraves dessa tabela, os resultados aparecem ok.

```
SELECT
    tabclientes.nome, 
    tabrepre.nome 
FROM
    tabclientes 
    inner join tabrepcli using (codcli) 
    inner join tabrepre using (codrepre);
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

```
 nome | nome
------+------
 A    | AA
 B    | AA
 C    | AC
(3 rows)
```

Sem repetição. Mas quando executamos a sua query, temos o resultado repetido. Olhando os valores da tabela vendedor, realmente, o codvend está repetido, logo vai repetir os dados. Mas olhando tambem o codrepre, vemos que a união dos 2 campos (codvend, codrepre) são únicas, tornando eles uma chave. Se mudarmos nossa query para levar isso em consideração, o resultado sai correto.

```
SELECT
    tabclientes.nome, 
    tabvendedor.nome
FROM 
    tabclientes 
    INNER JOIN tabrepcli USING (codcli) 
    INNER JOIN tabrepre USING (codrepre) 
    INNER JOIN tabvendedor USING (codvend, codrepre);
```

O resultado sai correto:

```
 nome | nome 
------+------
 B    | BA   
 A    | BB   
 C    | BD
```