# JOIN de 3 tabelas (LEFT JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com um dúvida referente a melhor forma (referente a performance e execução) de fazer o seguinte select... 
Inicialmente eu pensei em utilizar o LEFT JOIN, porém me deparo com algumas restrições na sua característica do LEFT JOIN.

Tendo 3 tabelas seguintes:

```
SERVICO
- S_ID
- S_CODIGO
- S_STATUS

ENTREGA
- E_ID
- E_CODIGO
- E_INFO
- D_FK_ID (FK com a tabela DIARIO, coluna D_ID)

DIARIO
- D_ID
- D_DATA
```

S_CODIGO (tabela SERVICO) e E_CODIGO (tabela ENTREGA) são incomuns e S_CODIGO possui mais dados e a Tabela de ENTREGA pertence a uma parte desses CODIGOS (por esse motivo pensei no LEFT JOIN).

```
SELECT 
    s.S_CODIGO AS CODIGO,
    s.S_STATUS AS STATUS,
    e.E_INFO AS INFORMACAO,
    d.D_DATA_INSERT AS DATA_CADASTRO
FROM
    SERVICO s
LEFT JOIN
    ENTREGA e
    ON e.E_CODIGO  = s.S_CODIGO
```

a partir desse select eu queria fazer mais um join para da Tabela ENTREGA (coluna D_FK_ID) com a Tabela DIARIO (D_ID) para buscar a coluna D_DATA_INSERT.

para retornar algo dessa forma:

```
CODIGO - STATUS      - INFORMACAO - DATA_CADASTRO
200    - CONCLUIDO   - DIURNO...  - 2018-11-05
201    - ANDAMENTO   - DIURNO...  - 2018-11-05
203    - CONCUIDO    - DIURNO...  - 2018-11-05
205    - CONCUIDO    - null       - null
210    - CONCUIDO    - null       - null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta incluir um novo `join` e adicionar a tabela "DIARIO":

```
SELECT 
    s.S_CODIGO AS CODIGO,
    s.S_STATUS AS STATUS,
    e.E_INFO AS INFORMACAO,
    d.D_DATA_INSERT AS DATA_CADASTRO
FROM
    SERVICO s
LEFT JOIN
    ENTREGA e
    ON e.E_CODIGO  = s.S_CODIGO
LEFT JOIN DIARIO d
    ON e.D_FK_ID = d.D_ID
```

Pode adicionar quantos `join` forem necessários. Copiei seu exemplo e fiz um `LEFT JOIN`, mas poderia ser qualquer outro tipo de `join`.

Aqui outra pergunta similar: [SQL JOIN múltiplas tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313399/sql-join-m%C3%BAltiplas-tabelas)